# Is it necessary to know kotlin to get AAD(Associate Android Developer) certification?

Tags: android, kotlin

Since google launched kotlin as official programming language for Android .
So is it easy to switch to kotlin ... Specially for beginners

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic on SO as it is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Quick google could have sorted this out pretty easily.

This page has all the info on the exam: 
https://developers.google.com/training/certification/associate-android-developer/#faqs\

These are all the resources Google designed for preparing students for the AAD: 
https://developers.google.com/training/courses/android-fundamentals